# JAVA OOD Question

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, uml

I have been learning Spring for past few months and found out that's its not only powerful but beautifully written framework. I want to write a small Forum Web Application using Spring, Spring Security, JPA, and for front end Jquery UI. Just for educational purposes I want to write this app. My problem is very simple i.e designing this application in like what classes, interfaces, what design patterns where to use. I am afraid of one thing I don't want to make it a cookie clutter just to add the things. I want to follow the right steps and make it so easy yet powerful that I can give it to community so that people can use it if they want. My main intention is to learn how to design a Java Web Application from scratch. How to design and I am only interested in Spring framework. And if somebody wants to do same thing, please join me because I believe that 1 is one and 2 are eleven. I would really appreciate if you guys can give me books names which you have followed them and made your life easier in Java world. UML and other tools which you have used please let me know and please suggest only those books and technologies which you have worked on and used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Best advice is to follow the Spring idiom as laid out in Spring MVC step by step.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This definitely is a great guide which will help me a lot. And also do you recommend any books which are easy to understand and give you every detail about how to think while developing a Web Application.Books which explains how to divide your code into Classes, Interfaces, Abstract Classes etc and how to design your application such a way that you can attach or detach other Open Sources or applications For example If I want to add another open source which shows me creating some kind of intermediate java code which will join two apps without making any changes in either one.